# Change Color of Selected Menu Item

Tags: asp.net

I know this is easy.  But the StaticSelectedStyle does not change the color of the menu button.

This is my Site.css file:

```
.panelMenu
{           
    width: 155px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.StaticSelectedMenuStyle
{
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 color: White;
 background-color: #66a598;
 border: thin outset #A9A9A9 !important; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.StaticMenuStyle
{
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 color: White;
 background-color: #006a54;
 border: thin outset #A9A9A9 !important; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.DMenuStyle
{
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 color: White;
 background-color: #008C71;
 border: thin outset #A9A9A9;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: medium;
 z-index: 110;
}
```

This is my asp:Menu in my Master.Page file:

```
 <body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <img alt="Heritage Valley Health System" src="Images/HVHS_Banner.jpg" style="width: 960px" />
    </div>
    <table class="style1" cellpadding="0px" align="left">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td id="cell_menu" valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server" CssClass="panelMenu" ScrollBars="None" >
                    <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server">  
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuStyle"/> 
                    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="StaticSelectedMenuStyle" />             
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Create Message"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/EditProfile.aspx" Text="Edit Profile"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/EditGroup.aspx" Text="Edit Group"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MessageReport.aspx" Text="Message Report"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Admin"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
                </asp:Panel>  
            </td>  
            <td id="cell_content" valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" CssClass="panelContent" ScrollBars="None">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" /> 
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Is there something else I need to set?
I just want the button in the Menu to be a lighter background color when selected.

Comment: Define "active" when on the Admin page, you want changes applied to the Admin item **or** when the nav item is in the process of being clicked?

Comment: When the user clicks a button on the menu, I would like the button to at least change color to indicate which page is being displayed or 'active'.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML mark up of how the control is rendered to the page? It has been awhile since I've used the asp:menu control and there are differences between .net 3.5 and .net 4. Basically you will need to add a style along the lines of `a:active` but you may need to do some restyling to get the `a` tag to fill its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've given you CSS for both table and list based options.

Basically you need to make the `a` tag fill the parent and use `a:active` to change color etc. I've used a bit of a quick solution to vertically center the text.

```css
.nav td, .nav li
{
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:center;
}

.nav a {
    display:block;
    background-color:#DDD;
    height:100%;
    line-height:30px;
    vertical-align:center;
    padding:0 3px;
}

.nav a:active
{
    background-color:#DDF;    
}


ul.nav {list-style:none; padding-left:0; }
ul.nav li {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<table class="nav" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>    

<ul class="nav" >
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Let me try this.  BTW...I am using 4.0.  The markup for the menu is on the Site.Master page.  What else are you asking for?

Comment: That worked!  The selection changes color when clicked.  Now, I can build on that and make them show as buttons and when selected that stay the color when clicked so the user knows where they are in terms of the menu selection.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there were some breaking changes since 4.0. if i understand it, you have to specify the 'selected' styles more directly in the markup, and not with css, such as:

```
<staticselectedstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      borderstyle="Solid"
      bordercolor="Black"
      borderwidth="1"/>
```

more detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I did that and it does nothing to change the button when selected.

Answer (score 0):

Does the css display correctly if the asp:Menu is outside of the table?

```
    <table class="style1" cellpadding="0px" align="left">
```

Comment: No.  The menu buttons do not change color when clicked if I take the asp:Menu out of the table.  The asp:Menu was still within the asp:Panel but without a table structure.

Comment: I presume you have the style sheet linked in the aspx page. Perhaps include the whole page?

Comment: Yes.  The style sheet is linked to the Site.Master.  All of the other style elements are displayed correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that if you change the color of the text (or some other css property) that it works but the background color doesn't work?

Try changing the the lower case "a" to "A".
ie. "background-color: #006a54;" to
background-color: #006A54;

Comment: No.  I am saying that in the Site.Master sheet I have many settings for other elements in the GUI such as controls and grids.  They are set appropriately.  I have the Menu styling set.  But when I try to change the color of the buttons in the Menu when they are selected.  The changes to the buttons (i.e. the background color of the buttons) do not change.